# In godot, how could I make an explosion not destroy occluded terrain?

Tags: simulations, godot, gdscript

This game is in 2D, and is made out of blocks.
Normally, I would simply erase blocks that aren't indestructible and are within range of the explosion. However, if blocks are behind something indestructible they will still get destroyed, and that's not what I want.

So how could I go about coding an explosion to not damage completely blocked  off terrain?

Comment: Presumably you've considered checking for a line of sight between the block and the explosion's center, using either a raycast or something like Bresenham's line algorithm over your tile grid?

Comment: I actually considered that. Haven't gotten to testing it though.

Comment: Great, try implementing it, and ask here if you have trouble making it work. :)